# Solr limits result to 10 by default

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

my solr queries (both in cqlsh and datastax driver powered java program) default the number of rows returned to 10; How can I get all the rows back in the result?

Answer (score 0):

By default solr limits the rows it return to 10.

try something like this from cqlsh

```
select id from empo where solr_query = '*:*' limit 1000000;
```

So add a big number after the limit.